# Can Warlocks choose the level effectiveness of Eldritch Blasts?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warlock, metamagic

Can a Warlock as defined in D&D 3.5 Complete Arcane choose to use a reduced-power eldritch blast?  Meaning if there is a level 5 warlock, will its eldritch blast always do 3d6 max caster level, or can it choose to do 1d6 with caster level 1 if desired?

On a related follow-up, the Complete Arcane states Warlocks can take Empowered and Quickened Spell-Like Ability feats from the Monster Manual.  However, from the monster manual for Empower Spell-Like Ability:

> The creature can only select a spell-like ability duplicating a spell
>   with a level less than or equal to half its caster level (round down)
>   –2.

If a warlock cannot choose what level to fire eldritch blast, then it can never empower or quicken the ability because it is always cast at maximum effectiveness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warlock's ability to regulate (to some degree) the effects of her *eldritch blast* (like damage) by lowering the *blast*'s effective caster level has no impact on her ability to pick or employ metamagic-like feats related to the *eldritch blast*.

## The *eldritch blast*'s spell level

The warlock's effective caster level of her *eldritch blast* isn't the same as the *eldritch blast*'s effective spell level. (This overuse of the word *level* dates to the game's inception, even [inspiring a favorite Web comic strip](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0012.html).) The spell level of *eldritch blast* was changed by the *Complete Arcane* [errata](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/errata):

> ### Page 7: *Eldritch Blast*
>
> **Second paragraph of the *Eldritch Blast* ability description:** Change “An *eldritch blast* is the equivalent of a spell whose level is equal to one-half the warlock’s class level (round down), with a minimum spell level of 1st and a maximum of 9th when the warlock reaches 18th level or higher” to “An *eldritch blast* is the equivalent of a 1st-level spell. If you apply a blast shape or eldritch essence invocation to your *eldritch blast* (see page 130), your *eldritch blast* uses the level equivalent of the shape or essence.”
>
> Any other references to *eldritch blast* being something other than the equivalent of a 1st-level spell should be disregarded. Any other references claiming that *eldritch blast* is not an invocation should be disregarded. A warlock can use *eldritch blast* at will. (1)

This means for most purposes except as pointed out by the errata the *eldritch blast* is effectively a 1st-level spell. Thus, for example, a warlock must possess at least a caster level of 6 (therefore usually being a level 6 warlock) to take the feats [Empower Spell-like Ability](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/monsterFeats.html#monster-feats) (*eldritch blast*) (*Monster Manual* 303) and Maximize Spell-like Ability (*eldritch blast*) (*Complete Arcane* 81), and a warlock must possess at least a caster level of 10 (therefore usually being a level 10 warlock) to take the feat [Quicken Spell-like Ability](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/monsterFeats.html#monster-feats) (*eldritch blast*) (*Monster Manual* 304).

## The *eldritch blast*'s caster level

Because, except for a few situations (like, for example, its lack of components), "a spell-like ability functions just like a spell" (*PH* 180), this means an *eldritch blast* can be employed "at a lower caster level than normal, but the caster level you choose must be high enough for you to cast the spell [i.e. employ the *blast*]…, and all level-dependent features must be based on the same caster level" (*PH* 171). Thus, a level 7 warlock could opt to employ the *eldritch blast* as if her effective caster level were, instead, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, or 1.

For example, to bring this all together, if she wanted to for some reason, a level 7 warlock that possesses the feat Empower Spell-like Ability (*eldritch blast*) can use the feat yet employ the *blast* as though her effective caster level were as low as 1.

Comment: Ah, the errata. OK, now my surprise makes more sense.